# Button that contains an Href with event

Tags: html, button, href

I have an href on a TEXT that is performing an action . (the action is changing the div i am using with another div).
I would like to change the TEXT as a BUTTON but i know i cannot innest a "button tag" into the "a tag".

```
    <a href="EXTERNALPAGE.html"  onmousedown="loadextPage(event) ">  BACKBUTTON </a> 

    <button id="back_button"> BACKBUTTON   </button>
```

In addition this is the code of the event:

```
      function loadextPage(event) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('pop_up_frame').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", event.target.href, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

### }

solved with

```
        <div id="back_button" onclick="return false" onmousedown="loadextPage(event)"                 style="cursor:pointer">
    <button>
        <a href="secondpopup.html">   Go Back </a>
    </button>
        </div>
```

and

```
<script>

    function loadextPage(event) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('pop_up_frame').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", event.target.href, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }




</script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Is it possible to make this a button, or why the event is not executed on click?

Comment: Both so i can understand.

Comment: `onclick="return false"` because of this link is not working try removing it

Comment: What is your idea in using the "onmousedown"? Is the onclick not an option for what you want?

Comment: Wait, so do you want it to be a button or not? Your code and question don't match

Comment: Do you want to execute loadextPage(event) on click or go to page.html? You are very unclear :)

Comment: it was because i copied  the code from another place i was using two event (one for onlclick and one for mousedown). I needed to have the onclick false but i had to have also another event one the same object. Since you cant have two onclick event on the same object.without using a function. Therefore i am updating the code now to explain better. Your solution did not work. thank you.

Comment: I udpate my question, hope its more clear.

Comment: @ Ian M -> yes i woul like to have a button,

Comment: @Bojan Petkovski -> I would like to have execute the loadextPage(event) which will change the div i am currently showing with another div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your function loadextPage(event) I know why you want an anchor tag, because the function is getting the href of the clicked element to load the external page. So you can use a button with data attribute like this

```
<button id="back_button" data-href="EXTERNALPAGE.html" onmousedown="loadextPage(event)"> BACKBUTTON   </button>
```

And you need to change you function to this

```
function loadextPage(event) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('pop_up_frame').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", event.target.dataset.href, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

So from this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", event.target.href, true);
```

To

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", event.target.dataset.href, true);
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/2vka9ubj/

Comment: I thank you for your interest. I follow your method but its not working so I was thinking about using a DIV and style the DIV as a button instead of using the tag Button but apparently wont work as well.

Comment: Why don't you style the a tag as button?

Comment: esyer to control what happen to the div since its a static element as long you dont add any listener. Button has a submit function so I thought there was something connected or..... i dont know... just trying. but i cannot get throw

Comment: I styled the div as a button

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```